# iOS 14 still display entire photo library despite of .limited status

Tags: ios, swift3

```
let accessLevel : PHAccessLevel = .readWrite
  let phStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus(for: accessLevel)
  if (phStatus == .notDetermined) {
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: accessLevel) {
      newStatus in
        if (newStatus == .limited) {
        var conf = PHPickerConfiguration()
        conf.selectionLimit = 1
        conf.filter = .any(of: [.images, .livePhotos])
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: conf)
        picker.delegate = self
        self.present(picker, animated: true)
      }
    }
  }
```

I use the code above to test iOS 14 new feature Limited Photos Library.
In the code I use new Api *authorizationStatus* and *requestAuthorization*,
and successfully get .limited status. But despite of .limited status, iOS 14 still display all
photo of the library. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 10):

The `.limited` status does not affect the PHPickerViewController. In fact, even a `.denied` status does not affect the PHPickerViewController!

The picker is out-of-process and does not involve user authorization. The way you are configuring and presenting the picker, you are asking for images, not for direct access to the photo library; and you receive only the image that the user personally chooses.

So prior user authorization is not needed and is completely irrelevant. All of your code before `var conf = PHPickerConfiguration()` can be deleted.

Comment: This is the right answer. 
`PHPicker doesn't require the user to grant photo library access.`